# Possible To Update a Form's Spreadsheet Without Full Permission (Google App Scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-forms

Is there a way to edit/manipulate a [Google Form](http://forms.google.com/)'s destination Spreadsheet without giving the app script [full Spreadsheet privileges](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets)? I didn't think this was possible but when enabling somne preferences, the below screenshot seemed to imply it was possible (at least to me).

[image]

The only way I know how to do this is from `spreadsheet.OpenByID` combined with the [destinationID property](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getdestinationid).

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

//Constants
  const thisForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const theSpreadsheetForTheForm = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisForm.getDestinationId());
```

However, when I authorized and ran, it failed due to lack of permissions. the parameters.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the situation of `edit/manipulate a Google Form's destination Spreadsheet without giving the app script full Spreadsheet privileges`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike, is it possible to change a Form's Spreadsheet (which can be referenced with `.getDestinationId()` *without* giving the form `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` (meaning the app could manipulate ALL spreadsheets)? I am pretty sure the answer is `no` but thanks for asking.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, for example, how about the following workarounds? W1: Use Sheets API. When Sheets API is used, you can select the scopes like `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`. In this case, the manifest file (`appsscript.json`) is used. W2: Use Web Apps as the wrapper. When Web Apps is used, the authorization can be done in the Web Apps. The client side can use the script of Web Apps with the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"`. If those were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, `W2` might want to learn more about. I'm not as familiar with that method. BTW, I checked out your GitHub page. You do some interesting stuff.  I may try your skillshare page.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your replying of additional information, I thought that Web Apps might be able to be used as the wrapper. In the case of Web Apps and you want to run the script as yourself, when Web Apps is deployed, the scopes are authorize. By this, when the user is run the script of Web Apps, the scopes are not required to be authorized because it has already been done. I thought that this might become the workaround for achieving your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without removing the @OnlyCurrentDoc statement (and, therefore, granting access to all spreadsheets in your drive).

Since the script isn't installed in your spreadsheet (it's installed in the form), it won't be able to access the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible without the full authorization scope for spreadsheets. You can see for yourself by explicitly providing authorization scopes in the manifest and then running the test function below (in the context of the form with set destination):

```json
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly"
  ]
}
```

```js
const checkDestinationAccess = () => {
    try {
        SpreadsheetApp.openById(FormApp.getActiveForm().getDestinationId());
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(`Expected spreadsheet to open, got error instead: ${error}`);
    }
};
```

You should get the confirmation of your suspicion that only the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` will help:

> Expected spreadsheet to open, got error instead: Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Comment: Shoot. Okay thanks. I'm going to accept the first answer but I upvoted your answer along with a different answer of yours about `try...catch` (topic I'm trying to get stronger on). Thanks for the detail.

Comment: @PGSystemTester - yeah, this is probably the best we've got when using GAS native API. Consider keeping an eye on the question in case Tanaike decides to write up an answer - I only put up a quick test to confirm the suspicion. Off-note: you explain your decisions too much, but it's nice to see feedback for a change :)

Comment: Re:`try...catch` - you mean defaults and optional properties?

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62462639/8276474 "Your try...catch answer").

Comment: @PGSystemTester - I didn't mean the post, I meant the topic :)